# Redash - Cascade Dropdown

Tags: cascadingdropdown, redash

is it possible (in Redash) to have two syncronized dropdown lists based on queries?
For example: list A shows some strings (Countries) from a query. When I select an item, list B shows some results(States) by query based on list A choice.

I tried and i cant achieve this functinality, only multiple choice and query filters alone available